# Java の calculation を使った3項以上の計算で結果が意図した通りにならない

Tags: java

Javaで電卓の作成をしており、ほぼ完成しているのですが、あとは3項以上の計算をできるようにしたいです。

例）1+2=3のような、2項の計算は問題なくできるのですが、3項になると　例）1+2+3=5となってしまいます。

これを　例）1+2+3=6となるようにし、どれだけ増えても計算できるようにしたいです。
その他、除算や乗算が出た場合　例） 1+2*3=9　というように、演算の優先順位は考慮していません。
どなたか教えていただけませんか。

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

class Key extends Panel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, kd, km, ks, ka, kdp, ke;

    Button createButton(String k, ActionListener listener) {
        Button b = new Button(k);

        add(b);

        if (listener != null) {
            b.addActionListener(listener);
        }
        return b;
    }

    Key(ActionListener listener) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20));

        k7 = createButton("7", listener);
        k8 = createButton("8", listener);
        k9 = createButton("9", listener);
        kd = createButton("/", listener);
        k4 = createButton("4", listener);
        k5 = createButton("5", listener);
        k6 = createButton("6", listener);
        km = createButton("*", listener);
        k1 = createButton("1", listener);
        k2 = createButton("2", listener);
        k3 = createButton("3", listener);
        ks = createButton("-", listener);
        k0 = createButton("0", listener);
        kdp = createButton(".", listener);
        ke = createButton("=", listener);
        ka = createButton("+", listener);
    }
}

class Test extends Panel implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BigDecimal b1, b2, b3;
    static int op = 0;

    JTextField t;
    Key key;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand() == "0") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("0")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "1") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("1")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "2") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("2")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "3") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("3")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "4") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("4")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "5") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("5")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "6") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("6")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "7") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("7")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "8") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("8")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "9") {
            t.setText(new BigDecimal(t.getText().concat("9")).toString());
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == ".") {
            if (t.getText().contains(".") != true) {
                t.setText(t.getText().concat("."));
            }
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "+") {
            BigDecimal buf = new BigDecimal(t.getText());
            if (b1.equals(null)) {
                b1 = buf;
            } else {
                b1 = b1.add(buf); 
            }
            op = 1;
            t.setText("");  
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "-") {
            b1 = new BigDecimal(t.getText());
            op = 2;
            t.setText("");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "*") {
            b1 = new BigDecimal(t.getText());
            op = 3;
            t.setText("");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "/") {
            b1 = new BigDecimal(t.getText());
            op = 4;
            t.setText("");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "=") {
            b2 = new BigDecimal(t.getText());

            switch (op) {
            case 1:
                b3 = b1.add(b2);
                break;
            case 2:
                b3 = b1.subtract(b2);
                break;
            case 3:
                b3 = b1.multiply(b2);
                break;
            case 4:
                b3 = b1.divide(b2, 11, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                break;
            default:
                b3 = new BigDecimal("0");
            }
            t.setText((b3).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        key = new Key(this);
        t = new JTextField();
        t.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        t.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        t.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 15));
        t.setEditable(false);

        add(t, "North");
        add(key, "Center");
    }

    public void start() {

        t.setText(new BigDecimal("0").toString());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame fr = new Frame("Calc");
        Test test = new Test();

        fr.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        test.init();

        fr.add(test, "Center");
        fr.pack();

        test.start();
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 変更してみたのですが、どこがおかしいですか？　今度は一回目の＋でエラーが出るようになりました。

Comment: b1がnullの状態で`b1.equals(null)`を呼ぶとエラーが発生します。`b1==null`に書き換えるとエラーは抑制できます。

Comment: 出来ました！凄く助かりました！本当にありがとうございます！！！

Answer (score 1):

加減乗除のボタンを押したときに`b1`変数の値をテキストの値で上書きしていることが原因です。
つまり`1+2+3=`と入力した時には、`1+2`の足し算を実行できていません。

- `1+`で`b1`は`1`になる
- `1+2+`で`b1`は`2`になる(意図していない動作)

これを意図通りに動かすためには下記のコードを書き換える必要があります。

```
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "+") {
            b1 = new BigDecimal(t.getText());   // ここでb1がテキストの値に変更されてしまう
            op = 1;
            t.setText("");
```

下記のような改修例が考えられます。
{}内の日本語は疑似コードですので適切に書き換えてください。
-*/の演算子についても同様の対応が必要です。

```
        } else if (e.getActionCommand() == "+") {
            BigDecimal buf = new BigDecimal(t.getText());
            if ({b1がnullなら}) {
                b1 = buf;
            } else {
                // 記号入力前の計算結果をb1に代入する
                b1 = {b1とbufを計算した値};  // 例えば 1+2+ と入力した場合、b1 = 1, buf = 2, op = 1として計算した結果をb1に代入する
            }
            op = 1;
            t.setText("");
```

ifの{}内の処理でb1,b2,b3変数にどのような値が入るのかを意識して開発することで、3項以上の計算に対応するコードの理解を深めることができると思います。
がんばってください。